# Simple MDE Editor for multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this plugin work for multiple IDs on a single form.

The plugin... [Simple MDE Editor](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor)

The code is following...

```js
<!-- Include the required files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>

<!-- Start simple MDE -->
<script>
    var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ 
        element: document.getElementById("MyID") 
    });
</script>
```

So far I tried:
1 - getElementsByClassName... no luck
2 - querySelectorAll... no luck
3 - listing the elements one-by-one...

```js
document.getElementById("id1") , 
 document.getElementById("id2") ,
 document.getElementById("id3") ,
 document.getElementById("id4")
```

Also no luck. How to do this for multiple elements in the same form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [element](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor): The DOM element for the textarea to use. Defaults to the first textarea on the page

This means you need to instantiate multiple **SimpleMDE** for each element:

```
var simplemde = {};

$('#id1, #id2, id3').each(function(idx, ele) {
    simplemde[ele.id] = new SimpleMDE({
        element: ele
    });
})
```

```js
var simplemde = {};

$('[id^="MyID"]').each(function(idx, ele) {
    simplemde[ele.id] = new SimpleMDE({
        element: ele
    });
})
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
    height: 50px !important;
    min-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="MyID1">MyID1</textarea>
<textarea id="MyID2">MyID2</textarea>
<textarea id="MyID3">MyID2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to apply SimpleMDE to **all** TextArea try this:

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
      var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
         element: this,
      });
   });
```

Regards!